# How to pass variable of current dashboard into link to another dashboard

Tags: post, request, get, prometheus, grafana

I have 12 servers which are scraped by Prometheus, and their metrics are shown in Grafana.

I can filter servers being shown on the dashboard by selecting desired servers in a dropdown for a variable `var`

Ex: `var="server1,server2";`. Variable can contain one or multiple servers being selected.

I am trying to make a link with current variable values being passed as parameters.

There is a link to a more detailed dashboard (for matters of this question should it be `link.to.gui/overview`).

Current situation is when you click onto this link, it shows you all servers without the filter, and you have to re-select desired servers again.

I would like to edit this link, so that it passes selected variables from the current dashboard to the detailed one.

I tried this way: `link.to.gui/overview?var=$var`, but got link like this: `link.to.gui/overview?var={server1,server2}`

It needs to be: `link.to.gui/overview?var=server1&var=server2`

All I can edit is the link itself, so i need a way to reformat the "$var" inside the link.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grafana supports [Advanced variable format options](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/dashboards/variables/variable-syntax/#advanced-variable-format-options), and specifically [query parameters format](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/dashboards/variables/variable-syntax/#query-parameters).

So in your example link will be `link.to.gui/overview?${var:queryparam}`. It will automatically convert variable into format supported by Grafana's dashboards.

Notice: contrary to your description, dashboards are expecting query parameters to be in format: `var-name_of_variable=first_value&var-name_of_variable=second_value` (at least in the current 9th version of Grafana).